# Making a endpoint API call

Tags: python-2.7, api

I am trying to fetch some data by an api endpoint call but below mentioned is the error that I get.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import json
import pprint
import urllib3
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
r=requests.get('api.dailysmarty.com/posts',auth=('abc','xyz'))
print (r.json())
pprint.pprint (r.json())
```

Following is the error that I get:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 511, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)'),))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to require authentication for Dailysmarty api's.
This is tested and returns you the JSON for the given endpoint.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://api.dailysmarty.com/posts/')
print(r.json())
```

Let me know in case you have any other questions.